# How to find the set of values of random variables, with the highest probability which has a given sum?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

There is a sequence of time intervals as normal distributions.
$$   t_i \sim  N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)  \qquad  \forall i \in [1..n] $$

I know $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ for all the distributions above. I need to find the sequence $t_1..t_n$ which has the highest probability such that,
$$  \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i = T $$

$T$ is the total time. Is there a known methodology to solve the problem above?

The solution I am working on right now: we have to maximize.

$$ P = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{N}(t_i; \mu_i,\sigma_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(t_i - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2} } $$
Then take log we get to maximize,
$$ log(P) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} -\frac{1}{2}2\pi\sigma^2 - \frac{(t_i - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}  $$

Then we ignore constants and multipliers we get to minimize,
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(t_i-\mu_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2} $$

I couldn't get any further but it looks like there should be a simple solution.

Comment: If the individual terms are independent $\sim  N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$ then their sum $T \sim  N(\mu_T,\sigma_T^2)$ where  $\mu_T=\sum\mu_j$ and  $\sigma_T^2=\sum\sigma_j^2$.  Then conditioned on $T=t$, the individual conditional distributions have mean, median and mode $\mu_i +(t-\mu_T)\frac{\sigma_i^2}{\sigma_T^2}$.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random has some justification

Comment: Thank you very much @Henry. This is exactly what I was looking for. <3